# Django : Why POST urls are not working in Django AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, url

I am creating a Like Button in Django using AJAX calls for my home page(where I have List of Posts which user can Like), For testing Logic of Like Button I had used normal(with page refresh) way to submit the form, and it works properly where I give URL as `action='{% url "like_post" %}'`. But when I went for AJAX based form submit I am Getting Error as `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/like/ 404 (Not Found)`.

template.py:

```
{% for post in all_posts %}
      <div class="posts" id="post-{{ post.id }}">
        <h2 class="thought-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
        <p class="content" id="{{ post.id }}" onclick="showWholeContent({{ post.id }})">
          {{ post.content }}
        </p>
        <div class="post-footer">
          <form id="like-form{{ post.id }}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit" id="{{ post.id }}btn" name="like" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn upvote">Like</button>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              {% for like in post.likes.all %}
                {% if like != user %}

                {% else %}
                  likingPost("{{ post.id }}btn");
                {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}

  // Adding AJAX for Like button
              $(document).ready(function(event){
                $(document).on('click', '#{{ post.id }}btn', function(event){
                  event.preventDefault();
                  $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '{% url "like_post" %}',
                    data: {
                      csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                    },

                    success:function(response){

                    }
                  });
                });
              });

            </script>
          </form>
                      </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('like/', views.like_post, name="like_post")
    .
    .
    .
]
```

views.py:

```
def like_post(request):
print("Insisde Like Post")
post = get_object_or_404(Posts, id=request.POST.get('like'))
if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
    post.likes.remove(request.user)                 # Liking The Post
    print("DisLiking the post")
else:
    post.likes.add(request.user)
    print("Liking the post")
return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Note: I am New To AJAX.Its my First Project which includes AJAX calls

Comment: I see a problem here - you are trying `id=request.POST.get('like')`, but posting via AJAX only `data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' },`. You also need to post  *like* key

Comment: Did you checked what's the value of `action` when you mention `action='{% url "like_post" %}'` ?

Comment: @MohammadUmair Yes, I checked my `action`, It works Properly.

Comment: @Chiefir Thanks a Lot. Me to figured this out few minutes after Posting the Question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out Solution after some time. And also Thanks to @Chiefir ,
In views.py I was looking for `like`, `post = get_object_or_404(Posts, id=request.POST.get('like'))`
Whereas, ajax call does not post any data JSON key `like`... So In `data` variable of template.py we just have make following changes...

```
data = {
    'like' : '{{ post.id }}'
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
}
```